Mysql is closing the connection on Ubuntu
I built a MERN app (used mysql instead of MongoDB)

I deployed it on the VPS (Ubuntu 24.04)
everything seems okay but when I try to check the logs of my backend using pm2 package it gives me kind of weird picture: first it gives me errors and then seems it is connected.
This is my db connection code
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dbHost = "127.0.0.1";
const databaseConnection = () => {
  const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'Test',
    password: 'Iwillnottell', 
    database: 'Test',
  });
  db.connect(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('MySQL Connected...');
  });
  return db; };
module.exports = databaseConnection();





Do not post images when plain text will do.

Is your mysqld configured to ask DNS to resolve the client's IP address to a hostname?  This often doesn't work (from lack of reverse DNS services) and makes every client session take a long time to connect.  It's usually better to disable DNS resolution in the mysqld config and just let it log IP addresses.

"You may lose the connection to a MySQL server due to network problems, the server timing you out, the server being restarted, or crashing. All of these events are considered fatal errors, and will have the err.code = 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'. See the Error Handling section for more information."
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#server-disconnects
I think maybe try to change the wait_timeout (idle timeout) of mysql and check for mysql error logs, maybe something is crashing.
